# Заменить знак вопроса в строке

Tags: строки, java

Приветов!

Задачка небольшая, но интересная: Заменить все знаки опроса в строке.Попробовал так:

```
srt.replaceAll("//?", "")
```

P.S Если ставить там обычный пробел он не работает...

И еще один вопрос, если можно, как заменить в строке все, что находится между круглыми скобками (в том числе и сами скобки)

Пример:

> (aaaa)aaa

Вывод:

> aaa

Помогите решить проблемку, пожалуйста!

Comment: @Yuri_Prime, попробовал поиграть с кодировкой  utf8Bytes = infoblock.getBytes("UTF8");
   String priwet2 = new String(utf8Bytes,"UTF8"); И нифига...

Comment: Коль скоро я не ошибаюсь, указывать кодировку в скобках надо ту, в которой исходный текст. Попробуйте поменять на Win1251, KOI8-R и прочие. И посмотрите в какой кодировке возвращает данные ваш метод. Очень может быть что он её не преобразует в UTF8

Comment: Попробовал, все равно не то.. Пробую тут вики парсить, то же самое неизвестные буквы на иврите не показывает и не читает, заменять скобки/символы не хочет, хотя сама страница в мета прописана как UTF-8.

Comment: Нашел решение вот здесь - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7703434/jsoup-character-encoding-issue

Забыл про существование поисковиков...Спасибо вам большое @Yuri_Prime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По поводу первого: экранировать надо обратным слешем, а не прямым, то есть получится

```
String resultString = srt.replaceAll("\\?", "");
```

Относительно второго - сложнее, но я бы написал так:

```
String resultString = srt.replaceAll("\\(\\w*\\)", "");
```

Однако, не совсем уверен насчёт экранирования скобок - без экранов они группы обозначают в регэкспе

Comment: У меня что-то ни-то ни другое не работает...Строка у меня не обычная,вот такая примерно: doc.select("meta[name=description]").get(0).attr("content") Добываю строку с помощью парсера Jsoup

Comment: Это становится интересным. Поправьте меня, если я не прав. Возможно проблема в кавычках внутри строки, хотя это маловероятно. А вы просто вызываете у переменной String метод replaceAll() или вызываете его, а возвращённый результат сохраняете? Я как-то на этом некисло обжегся, когда не мог понять, чего это у меня строка не изменяется.

Comment: Делаю так: String srt = doc.select("meta[name=description]").get(0).attr("content"); А потом вывожу System.out.println(srt.replaceAll("\\?",""));

Comment: Экранирование двойным обратным слешем:
    System.out.println(srt.replaceAll("\\\?",""));

Если причина и не в этом, тогда уже надо смотреть дальше и глубже.

Comment: Пардон там и есть двойной,просто ошибся..Так что надо копать дальше)

Comment: Посмотрите на строку, которая у вас подвергается замене. Может в ней дело. Может с ней что не так, вот он и не заменяет

Comment: всю строку что-то выложить не могу вот кусок: араб. ???? ????????? (араб. ???) Видимо символы не русские не отображает...

Comment: Поиграй с кодировкой. Это с ней проблема. Так что нужно перекодировать. Кажется, это Win1251, но тут я могу ошибаться.